# Find child where parent IS NOT a certain element

Tags: sql-server-2008, xquery, xquery-sql

I'd like to find an empty organisation element where it is not the immediate child of a parentProblem element.

Like so..

```
select * from Audit.PatientAudit pa
where pa.BeforeXml.exist('//*:organisation[not(../*:parentProblem)]') = 1
```

But it doesn't seem to work, any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
declare @T table(BeforeXml xml)

insert into @T values
('<root>
    <parentProblem>
      <organisation/>
    </parentProblem>
  </root>'), 
('<root>
    <anotherProblem>
      <organisation/>
    </anotherProblem>
  </root>'),
('<root>
    <anotherProblem>
      <organisation ID="1"/>
    </anotherProblem>
  </root>') 

select *
from @T pa
where pa.BeforeXml.exist('//organisation[local-name(..)!="parentProblem" and count(@*)=0]') = 1
```

Comment: +1 @Mikael Eriksson - Cheers but I worded my question slightly wrong. All the organsisation elements are empty but I want to find elements where there are no attributes! I know what attributes their are (only two) so I can explicitly check for there abscense with `not(@guid)` for example, but for completeness, is there a nicer way?

Comment: @Dog Ears - Updated answer. Did I understand you correctly, only rows with 0 attributes?